# Storing User data - NextAuth v3 with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication, next.js, onelogin, next-auth

In my NextJS app, am trying to use MongoDB to store the User data that's being used by the Next-Auth (v3) package.

Code from my `/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` file:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers'

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Providers.OneLogin({
            clientId: process.env.ONELOGIN_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.ONELOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
            domain: process.env.ONELOGIN_DOMAIN
        })
    ],

    callbacks: {
        
        jwt: async (token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) => {
            if (user) { //-- if success, store the id of the user in jwt token
                token.uid = user.id;
            }
           return Promise.resolve(token);
        },
        
        session: async (session, user) => {
            session.user.uid = user.uid;    //-- store the id of the user in the session data
            return Promise.resolve(session);
        }
    },
    
    // Optional SQL or MongoDB database to persist users
    database: process.env.MONGODB_URL
    // database: {
    //     type: "mongodb",
    //     useNewUrlParser: true,
    //     url: process.env.MONGODB_URL,
    // },
})
```

But it's always throwing the following error:

> [next-auth][error][session_error]
> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#session_error Error: optional
> dependency [mongodb] found but version [4.1.2] did not satisfy
> constraint [^3.5.9]

I have already installed the `mongodb` package. Am unable to figure out the issue. My MongoDB url is working fine as it is able to do other database operations(like adding new data, fetching, etc.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is that **major** version of the dependency is different and considered breaking: `"^3.5.9"` will satisfy updates within v3. Your version of `4.1.2` will be considered out of range as changes to the major of `4` would be considered significant/breaking.

**package.json**

```
 "peerOptionalDependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^3.5.9",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mssql": "^6.2.1",
    "pg": "^8.2.1",
    "@prisma/client": "^2.16.1"
  },
```

Update the `mongodb` version to support the change in major version i.e. `"mongodb": "^3.5.9 || ^4",` or `"mongodb": "^4",` etc

```
  "peerOptionalDependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^3.5.9 || ^4",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mssql": "^6.2.1",
    "pg": "^8.2.1",
    "@prisma/client": "^2.16.1"
  },
```